# How to launch a service app from another app in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, service

I have a service app with no activity. I want to connect it with my main app, because I will send data from main app to service, then get response from it. Service should be launched programmatically.

If they was in same project, i could tag it in manifest like <service android:name.../> . I tried to intent but packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage also didn't work. Other apps with activity works with this way but service app is different.

Main App - Try to intent

```
val i = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myexample.serviceapp")
if (i!=null) {
Log.d("MyService","Success")
startService(i)
} else {
Toast.makeText(this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Main App - Manifest

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.myexample.serviceapp"/>
</queries>
```

Service App

```
class RegistryService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("MyService","working")

        Thread {
            while (true) {
                Log.d("MyService","working 2")
            }
        }.start()

        return START_STICKY
    }
}
```

Service Manifest

```
<service android:name=".RegistryService" />
```

Comment: Why do you have two apps for this? "I tried to intent but packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage also didn't work" -- you do not have a launcher activity for that app ("I have a service app with no activity"), and even if you did, the launcher activity is not the service. You can add `android:exported="true"` and an `<intent-filter>` to the `<service>`, then construct an `Intent` matching the `<intent-filter>`. However, you will also need to think about security, which is why I am inquiring about whether having two apps is the best solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I made changes as you suggest. There was only `"android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"` action in `<intent-filter>`. Still I don't understand how to connect them. Is there a way make Main App as serviceClient ?

Comment: "There was only "android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" action in <intent-filter>." -- you probably should use your own custom action rather than one defined by the framework. "Still I don't understand how to connect them" -- `startService(Intent("android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"))`, based on what you described here.

Comment: I try to make my custom action as `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SALE_ACTION" />` in manifest. Then start service as `startService(Intent("android.intent.action.SALE_ACTION"))` but I don't know where to define package path `com.myexample.serviceapp` to my action. I know that intent should be explicit. Also intent services deprecated for API 30, can't I use that service as bound service? Is there a way to use `bindService()` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solve the problem.

```
val i = Intent().apply {
                this.setClassName("com.myexample.serviceapp", "com.myexample.serviceapp.RegistryService")
            }
            startForegroundService(i)
```